# How do I view and export table with slope data for raster and TIN?

Tags: raster, table, slope, tin

Using an original point file, I created a DEM raster with IDW interpolation as well as a TIN. I used surface analysis to create 3D slope layers, one with degrees for the raster (IDW) and one with percent for the TIN. I want to look at the tables with this slope data, and export them for a report. How would I do look at and export the slope values in a table?

Answer (score -1):

You do not specify the software?

In arcgis the "From TIN" toolset will convert the tin to another geometry from which you can get the attribute table.

While it is possible to "Build a Raster Attribute Table" with the tool of the same name in ArcGIS this is for integer format tables because these are likely to have a limited number of values for each of which a cell count can be given.

When you interpolate this produces a smoothly varying surface so each cell probably has a unique value to "n" decimal places. The table would then be a long list of cell values with cell count 1, which would be neither feasible to compute nor of much use.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-raster-attribute-table.htm

What you can do is reclassify to an integer raster (perhaps with many classes, depending on the accuracy needed), or convert the raster back to points in order to get a table with unique values for every cell.

Comment: Thank you! I am using ArcPro.. I can see the attribute table for the TIN.. but it only has the slope code. I see what the code is on the side panel, it's a range 0->1000. Would like to export these tables somehow.

Comment: When you say the side panel do you mean the symbology tab? Can you change the number of classes?